# PySpark - Date 0000.00.00 imported differently via function .to_date() and .csv() module

Tags: python, date, pyspark

I am importing data, which has a `date` column in `yyyy.MM.dd` format. Missing values have been marked as `0000.00.00`. This `0000.00.00` is treated differently depending upon the function/module employed to bring the data in the `dataframe`.

`.csv` file looks like this -

```
2016.12.23,2016.12.23
0000.00.00,0000.00.00
```

**Method 1:** `.csv()`

```
schema = StructType([
                StructField('date', StringType()),
                StructField('date1', DateType()),
        ])
df = spark.read.schema(schema)\
                    .format('csv')\
                    .option('header','false')\
                    .option('sep',',')\
                    .option('dateFormat','yyyy.MM.dd')\
                    .load(path+'file.csv')
df.show()
+----------+----------+
|      date|     date1|
+----------+----------+
|2016.12.23|2016-12-23|
|0000.00.00|0002-11-30|
+----------+----------+
```

**Method 2:** `.to_date()`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date, col 
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('2016.12.23','2016.12.23'),('0000.00.00','0000.00.00')],['date','date1']) 
df = df.withColumn('date1',to_date(col('date1'),'yyyy.MM.dd')) 
df.show()
+----------+----------+
|      date|     date1|
+----------+----------+
|2016.12.23|2016-12-23|
|0000.00.00|      null|
+----------+----------+
```

**Question:** Why two methods give different results? I would have expected the get `Null` for both. In the first case instead I get `0002-11-30`. Can anyone explain this anomaly?

Comment: There's no such thing as a Date 0. Yes, some databases use that as a "default" which causes all kinds of trouble when you try querying. Programming languages just choke on them. You should replace such bad values with `null` before you try parsing them

Comment: As for what happens, `to_date` tries to parse the value, chokes and returns `null`. With the first snippet though, you tell Spark that the column *is* a date with a format that doesn't match any data, `dd.MM.yyyy` instead of `yyyy.MM.dd`. I'd expect Spark to through, but it seems like the data was partially parsed with unexpected results

Comment: Thanks for your message. Regarding your second comment - well, that was a `typo` I editted it.

Comment: Are the results still the same though? This means parsing the CSV dates failed altogether, not just the 0 dates

Comment: In any case, most languages handle dates as offsets from an origin. `0` would refer to that origin

Comment: The results are different, with the first method I get `0002-11-30` and with second one I get `null`. I would have expected the same result, as ultimately we are using the same framework (`PySpark`).

Comment: I mean the dates in the first attempt. Do you still get `0029-06-07` for `2016.12.23`? If you do, even the good dates failed

Comment: I get dataframes from third party, and I don't know how that original dataframe was created from. So, that way I don't know if `0000.00.00` is stored as `0002-11-30` or `null`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I editted it now. Sorry for the confusion. I get `2016.12.23`.